# How to import Markdown files in SvelteKit?

Tags: import, markdown, sveltekit

```
<script>
    import Markdown from '../components/Markdown.svelte';
    import path from '../../static/assets/docs/overview.md';
</script>

<article class="prose prose-red max-w-none">
    <Markdown markdown={path} />
</article>
```

Here's the warning:

```
files in the public directory are served at the root path.
Instead of /static/assets/docs/overview.md?import, use /assets/docs/overview.md?import.
```

If I use `import path from '/assets/docs/overview.md';` I get the following error:

```
9:30:18 PM [vite] Internal server error: Cannot import non-asset file /assets/docs/overview.md which is inside /public.JS/CSS files inside /public are copied as-is on build and can only be referenced via <script src> or <link href> in html.
  Plugin: vite:import-analysis
  File: /Users/me/www/underwriting-ui/src/routes/docs.svelte
      at TransformContext.transform (/Users/me/www/underwriting-ui/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-713b45e1.js:67350:31)
      at async Object.transform (/Users/me/www/underwriting-ui/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-713b45e1.js:42397:30)
      at async doTransform (/Users/me/www/underwriting-ui/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-713b45e1.js:56738:29)
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, I will write an answer, but importing `markdown` file is like importing `string`, thus using `rollup-plugin-string` to convert text file to module should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same scenario - documentation in static markdown from which I need to generate HTML at build time. I ended up using [vite-plugin-markdown](https://github.com/hmsk/vite-plugin-markdown).

add this to your `vite.config.js`

```js
import { Mode, plugin as markdown } from 'vite-plugin-markdown'

const config = {
  plugins: [markdown({ mode: [Mode.HTML, Mode.TOC], ...})], ...
}
```

then in your svelte component

```js
import { toc, html } from '~/docs/api/auth.md'
```

I'm especially happy about "toc", which outputs something like:

```js
[{ level: '1', content: 'foo' }, { level: '2', content: 'bar' }, ...]
```

Comment: The plugin is not working with Vite 4+

Answer (score 7):

You can import a Markdown file (or any other file) as raw text via the `?raw` suffix. For example:

```
import my_markdown from "$lib/data/my_markdown.md?raw";
```

Paired together with rendering using `markdown-it`:

```
<script>
import MarkdownIt from "markdown-it";
import my_markdown from "$lib/data/my_markdown.md?raw";

const md = new MarkdownIt();
</script>

{@html md.render(my_markdown)}
```